# Can files in ActiveStorage be uploaded without parent(model) id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload, filepond

**situation:**

- rails: 6
- ruby: 2.5.3
- filepond: 1.0.0
- I've got a model (Parent) that has_many_attached :attachments. When I'm
  creating a new Parent, there is a basic form and FilePond jquery
  library to easier manage drag&drop.

**problem:**

Creating new parent with files.

- As I understand, FilePond does not attach files to the form, thus I
  get InvalidSignature error. If I remove :attachments from params,
  Parent is created successfully, though params[:attachments] before deletion is nil.

So, I want to generate new Parents and to attach files to some of them during creation (if user chooses to).

**attempts:**

- So I'm able to upload files when ***updating*** Parent because then I
  have *Parent.id* and I am able to generate a specific link for a FilePond.
- I've tried to upload Parent first and after successful upload, attach the files.

So I would like the latter attempt to work as it seems to be the most suitable option.

### parent_form

```
= simple_form_for(parent, url: [parent], remote: true) do |f|
= f.file_field :attachments, multipart: true, id: "filepond"
```

### parent.js

```
  $('#document-modal').on('shown', function() {
    var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    var pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);

    FilePond.setOptions({
      allowMultiple: true,
      instantUpload: false
    });
  });
```

### parent_controller

```
  def create
    params[:parent].delete :attachments
    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
    render('errors') unless @parent.save
  end

  def update
    params[:parent].delete :attachments
    @parent.update(parent_params)
  end

  def create_attachment
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
    @parent.attachments.attach(params[:parent][:attachments])
    head :ok
  end
```

Comment: FilePond dev here. I don't have any experience with ActiveStorage but wanted to post this link on why FilePond can't update the existing input, this is unfortunately a browser limitation, see for more info: https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Turns out, I took the wrong approach dealing with this form. All I had to do is submit the form without any attachments, then receive database record id and use that id to generate the url for attachment uploads. So steps:
submit the form (noattachments; ajax) -> Backend returns record id -> use record id in FilePond server url generator -> use onProcessFile or onProcessFiles to show the error/success response in the front.